# In awk or nawk, how do I use the last occurrence of pipe character as field delimiter, giving me 2 fields?

Tags: regex, awk, nawk

I would prefer to not use gawk-only features as I will need to run this on various UNIX flavors and not all of them have gawk.   I have a file with lines like this:

```
^myfile\..*\.(pork|beef)$|send -d j
^myfile\..*\.(chicken|turkey|quail)$|send -d q
^myfile\..*\.cheese$|send -d u
```

Sometimes, but not always, the first field contains one or more pipe characters.  The characters after the last pipe can reliably be called field 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is entirely portable but I think it is:

```
awk '{
    # Find the position of the last "|" in the line.
    p=match($0, /\|[^|]*$/)

    # "Split" the line into two fields around that position.
    a[1]=substr($0, 1, p-1)
    a[2]=substr($0, p+1)

    printf "[%s] [%s]\n", a[1], a[2]
}' file.in
```

As indicated by Ed Morton in the comments the use of `p` here is unnecessary as the awk `match` function also sets the `RSTART` variable to the position in the string where the regex matched so the above could also be written this way:

```
awk '{
    # Find the last "|" in the line.
    match($0, /\|[^|]*$/)

    # "Split" the line into two fields around that position (using the RSTART variable from the match() call).
    a[1]=substr($0, 1, RSTART-1)
    a[2]=substr($0, RSTART+1)

    printf "[%s] [%s]\n", a[1], a[2]
}' file.in'
```

In fact doing effectively this *exact* task is the example of `match()` in the [awk Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-47).

Comment: Slam dunk!  Yes that is portable.  Works great on Linux, HP-UX, AIX, and Solaris with /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk.  Thanks!

Comment: @EdMorton I was going to use `RSTART` at first but thought that `p=` was a bit more self-documenting.

Comment: @EdMorton Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set `FS` to `$|`:

```
$ awk -F'[$][|]' '{printf "[%s$] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' file
[^myfile\..*\.(pork|beef)$] [send -d j]
[^myfile\..*\.(chicken|turkey|quail)$] [send -d q]
[^myfile\..*\.cheese$] [send -d u]
```

You can tack the `$` back onto the end of `$1` if you like:

```
$ awk -F'[$][|]' '{$1=$1"$"; printf "[%s] [%s]\n", $1, $2}' file
[^myfile\..*\.(pork|beef)$] [send -d j]
[^myfile\..*\.(chicken|turkey|quail)$] [send -d q]
[^myfile\..*\.cheese$] [send -d u]
```

Another approach if you prefer would be:

```
$ awk '{f1=f2=$0; sub(/\|[^|]*$/,"",f1); sub(/.*\|/,"",f2); printf "[%s] [%s]\n", f1, f2}' file
[^myfile\..*\.(pork|beef)$] [send -d j]
[^myfile\..*\.(chicken|turkey|quail)$] [send -d q]
[^myfile\..*\.cheese$] [send -d u]
```

Comment: Yes but how can you be sure there is always a `$` before the last pipe?

Comment: Because the OP showed in their sample input that there's always a `$` before the last pipe and you can see that there's a start-of-string anchor at the start of every first field and so it's reasonable to expect an end-of-string anchor at the end of each, as also shown in the sample input. No point complicating the answer unnecessarily and the OP can always provide different input if this answer won't always work.

Comment: Yes, this is very interesting and something to think about.   The ^ and $ anchors in field 1 are not requirements.  They are typical characteristics of the data in field 1, and I suppose we could turn them into hard requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too (for example I choose the tab as new separator):

```
awk -vRS='[|]' -vORS='' 'NR>1{printf /\n/?"\t":"|"}1' file
```

Comment: Not putting a space between `-v` and the variable name makes it gawk-specific and a multi-char RS is undefined by POSIX so while gawk will assume you mean it's an RE, other awks could just use the first char or do anything else with it. To make the above POSIX, it'd be `-v RS='|'` - you don't need to escape the `|` since it's just a single char and so it has it's literal meaning in all awks.